# Log file name does not respect the specified index

Tags: java, log4j

I just set up my log4j to have log file named by date and index size, configuration below works well

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE,monAppender
log4j.appender.monAppender=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.monAppender.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy  
log4j.appender.monAppender.RollingPolicy.MinIndex=1 
log4j.appender.monAppender.RollingPolicy.maxIndex=5
log4j.appender.monAppender.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.monAppender.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy  
# 5 Mo just for testing
log4j.appender.monAppender.TriggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=5242880
log4j.appender.monAppender.RollingPolicy.fileNamePattern=D:/log/MyApp_log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log
log4j.appender.monAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.monAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=|------->| [%-5p - SI] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss}]  [%m] %n
```

But the generated index is random and violating the constraint mentioned above (**minindex = 1, maxindex = 5**), the generated files are named as following:

[image]

My question is how this index is generated? how to initialize? if this is impossible, it is a risk that the same index is regenerated again which will overwrite an existing file!

jar used: **log4j-1.2.17.jar, apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar**.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: `%i` should work as per https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/FixedWindowRollingPolicy.html

Comment: according to the link you have provided to me, it should work :s, and the big problem is that we can not debug this kind of treatment (from what I know) to detect when and how the %i is initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config is wrong:

```
log4j.appender.monAppender.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy  
log4j.appender.monAppender.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
```

You can't specify two different policies for the same appender. The second line will overwrite the first one, replacing the `FixedWindowRollingPolicy` with the `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`. In the `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`, `%i` is probably the seconds since the Epoch.

If you want an index and a timestamp in the file name, you'll have to write your own policy.